# QuerySet' object has no attribute 'posts'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Am having a challenge to get users post on their timeline and I would appreciate if anyone could help me. I keep coming against this error(QuerySet' object has no attribute 'posts') when ever filter through the post object. I wonder what am missing out on here ? here is my model for post.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, blank=True)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='path/post/img' ,blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name="users") 
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

here is my view for users account since i want every user to have their  post on their timeline.

```
def account_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    - Logic here is kind of tricky
        is_self
        is_friend
            -1: NO_REQUEST_SENT
            0: THEM_SENT_TO_YOU
            1: YOU_SENT_TO_THEM
    """
    context = {}
    user_id = kwargs.get("user_id")
    try:
        account = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except:
        return HttpResponse("Something went wrong.")
    if account:
        context['id'] = account.id
        context['username'] = account.username
        context['bio'] = account.bio
        context['get_full_name'] = account.get_full_name
        context['email'] = account.email
        context['profile_pic'] = account.profile_pic.url
        context['cover_image'] = account.cover_image.url
        context['city'] = account.city
        context['country'] = account.country
        context['gender'] = account.gender
        context['hide_email'] = account.hide_email

        try:
            post_list = Post.objects.filter(user_name=account)
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            post_list = Post(user_name=account)
            save.post_list()
        posts = post_list.posts.all()
        context['posts'] = posts

        try:
            friend_list = FriendList.objects.get(user=account)
        except FriendList.DoesNotExist:
            friend_list = FriendList(user=account)
            friend_list.save()
        friends = friend_list.friends.all()
        context['friends'] = friends
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change to: posts = post_list.all()

Comment: thank you and it help solve the problem! @Marcello Bastos

Comment: @AbubakariUmarblacKrussainUma please mark this answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @AbubakariUmarblacKrussainUma, You're welcome!